# Issue with CRYPTO library in F5 BIG-IP: missing required parameter

Tags: encryption, tcl, f5, big-ip

i'm writing and iRule for the F5 Big-Ip v. 11.x. I have an issue with the CRYPTO library.

When I try to decrypt a string in this way

```
set  foo [CRYPTO::decrypt -alg rc4 -keyhex $key $to_decrypt]
```

where $key is a string in hex format and $to_decrypt is the encrypted string.

I receive an error:

> tmm err tmm[7107]: 01220001:3: TCL error: /Common/testirule
>    - Missing required parameter

Here you can find the documentation: https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.CRYPTO__decrypt.ashx

I can't understand which parameter is missing, can you help me? Thanks in advance!

edit: I add here a snippet from documentation:

> CRYPTO::decrypt [-alg <>] [-ctx <> [-final]] [-key[hex] <>] [-iv[hex]
>   <>] []
>
> decrypts data based on several parameters
>
> **alg** - algorithm. ASCII string from a given list (see below) The
>   spelling is lowercase and the iRule will fail for anything not in the
>   list. In ctx mode, alg must be given in the first CRYPTO::command and
>   cannot be modified.
>   **ctx** - context is the name of a Tcl variable and
>   can only be generated from and used in CRYPTO commands. Notes: Trying
>   to get or set value for a ctx variable will fail. When a CTX variable
>   is first used in iRule, a tcl object will be generated from the given
>   arguments (alg, key, iv, etc.). A given CTX variable can only be used
>   for one CRYPTO:: command. An iRule
>   CRYPTO:: command would fail if CTX is reused for different purpose.
>   “–final” must be used for the last CRYPTO:: command for the same CTX
>   variable to finish the CRYPTO:: command. After “-final” is used, the
>   CTX variable will be freed and the same ctx variable name can be
>   reused. When a CTX variable already has a key and an IV value stored
>   in it, the value can only be updated before CRYPTO command really
>   starts, that is before any data is given. After the command starts and
>   before it finishes, updating key or IV in CTX would fail. **key** - key
>   (binary data). Key length is determined by alg used. Can be generated
>   by CRYPTO::keygen **keyhex** - key as hex data. Key length is determined
>   by alg used. Can be generated by CRYPTO::keygen **iv** - initialization
>   vector (binary data). Length is determined by alg used. Can be
>   generated by CRYPTO::keygen **ivhex** - initialization vector as hex data.
>   Length is determined by alg used. Can be generated by CRYPTO::keygen

Comment: That site requires a login…

Comment: i know, unfortunately i cannot provide the access :( I'll added some stuff to the question from the documentation

Comment: I wonder whether the rc4 algorithm requires additional pieces (i.e., additional “optional” arguments such as `-ctx` or `-iv`). Don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-iv` is optional because you could have created a context containing the initialization vector and passed that in with `-ctx` instead. TCL command documentation does not have a good way of indicating this situation: `-iv` and `-key` are required OR `-ctx` is required.